# SP Flash Tool does not recognize the firmware scatter file

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, unbricking, device-firmware, mediatek

I have a neffos X1 Lite and it seems that it boots only in the twrp recovery console.

Anyway I am trying to restore my official recovery console (i have no backup) using the official firmware http://www.neffos.com/en/support/download/X1-Lite

Inside this zipped file, there is a file scatter.txt that contains the following content.

```
preloader 0x0
pgpt 0x0
recovery 0x8000
para 0x1008000
expdb 0x1088000
frp 0x1a88000
ppl 0x1b88000
nvdata 0x1bc8000
metadata 0x3bc8000
protect1 0x5bc8000
protect2 0x63c8000
seccfg 0x7000000
proinfo 0x7040000
oemkeystore 0x7800000
md1img 0x8000000
md1dsp 0x9800000
md1arm7 0x9c00000
md3img 0x9f00000
nvram 0xa400000
lk 0xa900000
lk2 0xaa00000
boot 0xab00000
logo 0xbb00000
tee1 0xc300000
tee2 0xc800000
secro 0xcd00000
keystore 0xd300000
system 0xe000000
cache 0xeb800000
userdata 0x106800000
flashinfo 0xFFFF0080
sgpt 0xFFFF0000
```

Now, using *SP_Flash_Tool-5.1916_Win* to load this scatter file I get an error "Invalid format". So, how am I supposed to un-brick my phone? I still have access to ADB, Fastboot and no matter what I can not boot to OS.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have unlocked bootloader and the fastboot it works but as I said the TWRP seem to work but I can not boot to the OS.... Everytime I boot I go to the recovery console. So, I thought I could flash the official firmware to return back to official recovery.

Comment: @alecxs Please explain what do you mean "already stock"

Comment: you have right but I am desperate and I thought to get full restoration to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ROM you provided does not contain a valid scatter file or recovery.img so you can not use SP Flash Tool.

I recommend you to make a backup of boot, copy the boot.emmc.win to PC, then to another phone and patch it with Magisk Manager apk

After successful patching, copy the patched file back to PC

Reboot the phone to bootloader, and flash the magisk_patched.img from fastboot

```
fastboot flash boot "C:\adb\magisk_patched.img"
```

If for whatever reason you are not allowed to flash from fastboot, you can flash it from TWRP

When phone is working, just install Magisk Manager apk

**Note:** The /system partition and /data partition are encrypted, thats why you can not install Magisk.zip from TWRP

Patching the boot.img with Magisk Manager will remove the "verify" flag and patch against dm-verity, which will allow you to boot with modified recovery partition

**Edit:**

If you have a working similar phone, you can perform a "Read Back" of the recovery partition. based on your question, i have created a scatter file for the recovery partition

for the read back, select Region EMMC_USER and use the start address and size from this:

```
############################################################################################################
#
#  General Setting 
#    
############################################################################################################
- general: MTK_PLATFORM_CFG
  info: 
    - config_version: V1.1.2
      platform: MT6755
      project: TP904A
      storage: EMMC
      boot_channel: MSDC_0
      block_size: 0x20000
############################################################################################################
#
#  Layout Setting
#
############################################################################################################
- partition_index: SYS2
  partition_name: recovery
  file_name: recovery.img
  is_download: true
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x8000
  physical_start_addr: 0x8000
  partition_size: 0x1000000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: UPDATE
  is_upgradable: true
  reserve: 0x00
```

**Edit 2:**

based on your output of /proc/partitions from twrp here is the complete scatter file (use carefully, no warranty it works)

[MT6755_Android_scatter_TP904A.txt](https://www.mediafire.com/file/t03micajo3t0pp4/MT6755_Android_scatter_X1lite-TP904R2907.zip)

Comment: ok, i will try right now. I have two similar phones (one of them has the problem, but the other is running official firmware without any modifications)

Comment: To run Magisk Manager  apk should I have a rooted phone?

Comment: Magisk Manager is up to date and just above Magisk is not installed. Should I install it ? Does this affect or root my other phone ?

Comment: I have also copied to my sdcard the Magisk-v19.2.zip and the SR5-SuperSU-v2.82-SR5-20171001224502.zip and when installed them under twrp I see no difference in the booting procedure.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to mention that I tried to install magisk.zip or SuperSu.zip without success. So, Magisk Manager apk will root my working phone? Because without Installing I can not find any patching option inside the app, am i wrong ?

Comment: thanks, i am doing this right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95331/discussion-between-alecxs-and-maverick).

Comment: Excellent programmer & human. He helped me so much with direct support that I have no words to thank him. Alecxs, If you ever visit Greece, you are very welcome to stay at my home. Thank you is too little for the help you gave me.

Comment: in the excel scatter computation file you gave me, there is an inconsistent after the oemkeystore section in comparison the official firmware scatter.txt I attached in my question.  Your computations are correct so why these inconsistent exists? Which of them are the correct values? Check the edited excel file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EKOYEsjXiqzA32RYbP3rH2C0ZAHsjJk/view?usp=sharing and the Text Tab

Comment: Alecxs great news! After "ReadBack" from an identical phone, I finally restored the original recovery image and now the phone it works as it should be. I will never accomplish that without your precious help. I learned a lot, but the best part? Don't touch anything you don't know how to handle it. I spent 24 hours almost continuously (with 4 hours sleep between them) to make it work, I lost my time with this thing and I feel very very tired. I will spend a little time with my children now! Thank you again what else can I say?